# Why do Windows file windows populate faster than OSX?

Tags: windows, macos

I apologize for only having anecdotal data available, but whenever I use a Windows machine I'm impressed with how quickly a window loads its directory information. My mac often takes several seconds to populate its windows.

I've noticed this ever since Windows XP, so I wonder if the cause lies in a core architecture difference between the platforms.

**Note**: I'm aware the "All My Files" smart folder in OSX is performing a complex query of some kind and that slows it down. I'm only interested in the differences between the "dumb" folders.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered in its current form.

Comment: Are you just curious or is there a problem to solve here?